# How can I display my meta value in a textarea?

Tags: post-meta, text

I have this saved:

```
$description = get_post_meta( $postID, 'video_desc', true );
```

and then have used this in my form in textarea:

```
value="<?php echo $description; ?>"
```

When I check the console it is there as the value but it is not displaying in the textarea. I am wanting this to show the text as it is in a edit-post.php page/file.

I have been searching for hours!! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To add code in a question, indent each line with 4 spaces or highlight the code and click on the `{}` sign above the editor to put your code in a code block or backticks :-)

Comment: That is not how a textarea works: http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_textarea_tag.cfm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the textarea must be printed between the opening and the closing tag:

```
<form action="/">
    <textarea name="whatever"><?php echo esc_textarea( $description ); ?></textarea>
</form>
```

Note the usage of the function `esc_textarea()` here. It prevents any possible character inside the variable `$description` from being interpreted as HTML. It's an important step to avoid possibly XSS vulnerabilities.

There are many more escaping functions like `esc_attr()`, `esc_html()` or `esc_url()`. You should know about them and how they are meant to be used: https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation